# Route on components Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Can i route on components to specific page? i would like to route somewhere after like() process done

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { GamesService } from '../games.service';
import { IGames } from '../games';

  constructor(private router:Router, public route:ActivatedRoute, private gs:GamesService) { }

  like(id:string,l:string){
    if(l == 1){this.likes=0 }else{this.likes=1};
    this.gs.like(id,this.likes).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        // this.game=data;
        console.log(data);
         router.navigate(['wishlist'];
      }
    );
  }
```

i got this error messsages

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DetailComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component where you have the `like` method (let's name that component as Abc)

**abc.component.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
}

like(id:string,l:string) {
    if (l == 1) {
        this.likes=0;
    } else {
        this.likes=1;
    }
    this.gs.like(id,this.likes).subscribe((data) => {
       console.log(data);
       router.navigate(['otherComponentPath']); add this
    });
}
```

**abc.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AbcComponent } from '<path to the component>';
import { AbcRoutingModule } from '<path to the abc routing module>';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        RouterModule,
        AbcRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        AbcComponent,
        OtherComponent 
    ]
})
export class AbcModule {
}
```

**abcRouting.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    path: 'otherComponentPath', //this will be in the url
    component: OtherComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AbcRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: and do you have set route ? in the `routing.module` ?

Comment: I’ve set it on app.module.ts

Comment: I got this error when i insert the private router:Router on constructor

Comment: which error? Have you imported the RouterModule ? `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` and then add `RouterModule` into the `imports` ? (do it in the module where you have declared the component)

Comment: i just edited my post that include import, constructor, function, and the error messages

Comment: Dont add `RouterModule` import into the component, but into the module, where you have declared the component, see my updated answer

Comment: if i didn't import the RouterModule on the component it won't work it got same error as previous... if i import the `Import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` and on the constructor i insert `private router:RouterModule` the error says `Can't find variable router `

Comment: in the component, you need just only to add 
`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`
and in the `constructor` - `private router: Router` (you can't import RouterModule there...)

Comment: Idk why but the function just can’t detect the private router:Router the error says can’t find variable router

Comment: hmm, ok, glad you figured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

In your component constructor,

```
constructor(private _router: Router)
```

and modify your function as following:

```
like(id:string,l:string){
  if(l == 1){this.likes=0 }else{this.likes=1};
  this.gs.like(id,this.likes).subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this._router.navigate(["/routeurl"])
    }
  );
}
```